# How to save an Excel file created with PHPExcel, without dialog?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to generate an Excel file (xls), using [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/), but have it saved on the server instead of having it prompted for download on my desktop!

How can I instruct PHPExcel to save my file instead of having the dialog presented by the browser?

Answer (score 8):

Ok, I get it:

I have to use:

```
$objWriter->save('nameoffile.xls');
```

... and not to define headers, because header "telling" to browser to save file.

Thank you anyway!